# How to plot a step function with close and open ends for each domain without plotpiecewise?

Tags: plotting

I want to show a continuous time Markov chain and I want to plot something like below:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing! I don't know how to put black and white circles.

Comment: but my wolfram mathematica version is 11.3.0 and can't recognise the plotpiecewise code!

Comment: @sarakaviani: The code in the linked Q&A works for me.  You did enter and execute the definition of the `PlotPiecewise` function didn't you ?

Comment: I wrote and execute PlotPiecewise in mathematica space and it was unknown for that!